# modelformset_factory with can_order

Tags: python, django

I am using modelformset_factory with can_order:

```
BrandFormSet = modelformset_factory(Brand, can_order=True, can_delete=True, extra=0)
```

And in my views I have:

```
<form ...>
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.ORDER }}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

It's showing correctly:

```
<input id="id_form-1-ORDER" name="form-1-ORDER" type="number" value="2" />
...
```

My Brand model looks like this:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now how can I tell Django that `order` field is where to save the ordering?

Comment: you can override the `.save` method for the model, though I have to admit I'm kinda confused about what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: @yuvi I need to save the order.

Comment: That much I understand. But the whole point of saving the order seems weird (and `can_order` wasn't created for that purpose). I'm trying to understand the bigger picture, and maybe offer an alternative solution that would be easier to maintain